# Whirlpool Duet dryer won’t heat

Tags: electrical

The dryer wouldn’t heat when I got it. I replaced the heating element with a new one. It worked great for about 6 weeks, but now it won’t heat. When I replaced the new one I cleaned out all the lint that was down in access panel. I’m confused.

Comment: I would think the problem might be in the control or sensors.  Unless the element was defective or was not  put in right, it should last a long time.  I would search for the wiring diagram for that model of dryer and test.

Comment: The sensors are easy to test.   When I was locating one on my dryer, the connection spade lug had broken off.  Probably due to vibration.   They test open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are qualified open the dryer up and turn on the heat and measure the voltage at the heater, it should be 220V. If not the heater is probably OK. Measure at the incoming point of the dryer, if that is not 220V your dryer is probably OK*. If it is 220V you will then need to troubleshoot for problems in the dryer wiring. Please be careful, a mistook at these voltages can kill you.

*Since you do not have 220V at the dryer turn the breaker off then on several times and then leave it on. Measure again if you have 220 and the breaker was not tripped it may need to be replaced. If not there is a problem in the wiring. To be sure and measure the voltage at the breaker, if you have 220 at the breaker the problem is in the wiring / connections to the dryer. If not you need to call your power provider as you probably have problems with the main service.

If you are comfortable you can validate this by checking the 220V coming in from the mains where they connect to the panel.

This should give you a good idea where the problem is. If the element is defective try for a warranty replacement and validate the air flow in the dryer.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start...

- Look for a service manual or "tech sheet" that applies to your model, similar to [this one](https://usermanual.wiki/Pdf/W10177459AWhirlpoolDuetSportDryerTechSheet.223347982/pdf). A printed tech sheet may be somewhere inside your machine, possibly folded up and/or in a plastic pocket attached to a flat surface. Whirlpool publishes very nice ones, and they often include details that are essential but hard to discover. It's also the kind of information that "wants to be expensive" — so Google may be your friend, or... not. YMMV
- You will need to use a volt/ohm meter or DMM, and understand basic electric circuits to do much troubleshooting. Don't worry, I mean *really* basic, so I will assume that.
- Check there is power and a good neutral (in previous answer). And it bears repeating **be careful** working around live wires, particularly 220 or 240 volts. At a minimum you will get a good buzz from 120V, so consider 240V is double that.

In general, an electric dryer needs several things all working in order to heat up. They are the components of the heater circuit, or think of them as "things that must be true" for the heater to come on.

- Power, which may be wired directly to to one of the components or supplied via the control board.
- The heating element itself (of course!)
- The temperature to be lower than normal drying temperature. There could be a separate thermostat, or a sensor connected to the control board.
- The temperature to be lower than the max "safe" temperature. There is almost always a second, separate thermostat for this.
- The door closed. The door switch may be wired directly into the heater circuit, or via the control board.
- The control board to turn the heater "on" — obvious stuff like actually running, a cycle with heat selected (not "air fluff"), and so on.

Troubleshooting is just a matter of checking each of those. The tech sheet or manual should show what components your model has and which functions are done by the control board. There may be some others, like sensor(s) for the fan blowing or drum turning, but they are rare.

Start troubleshooting with individual components like the heating element and thermostat(s) that you can check statically, without power or the machine running. Just locate each one, disconnect the wires, then check for the correct resistance. Thermostats and the door switch are just on/off switches, and should measure zero. The heating element should be a low value, one or two digits, but more than zero. (Check the tech sheet/manual, or use the wattage and Ohm's Law if you like.) And yes, it can be a real PITA reaching some with your DMM probes.

If you don't find any faults, move on to power and the control board — parts where the machine has to be powered and running. Check for power to the control board. Seeing lights come on is usually enough, but best to use the DMM. If power is wired to something else first, check that.

Start the cycle, and wait until the control board should have enabled the heater (normally delayed a minute or two). Check for power where the heating circuit connects to the control board. If there is no way to connect the DMM leads at the board — they may not fit - try at the heater or another component. You can also pull the control board out and connect to the solder pads on the back side, or try a non-contact voltage tester.